# Can't save DB password in BDE Admin v5.01 (c. 1998)

Tags: database, password

I have a legacy version of Goldmine running which uses BDE to connect to an SQL2005 server. I'm moving the goldmine application and its database onto a new server and all is fine with the exception of the master DB password.

When Goldmine starts it prompts for the password. I enter the password and all is fine but I want the prompt to go away. The password appears to be saved and obfuscated somewhere on the old server but this was configured before my time.

As best I can determine, I use the bdeadmin.exe tool to modify the idapi32.cfg file but there is no password option.

Answer (score 1):

No password is saved in the BDE configuration file.

You need to go into the properties of each of the GOLDMINE users inside of GoldMine (file|configure|users settings) and to the access tab there.  At the bottom of the tab are the saved SQL username and password credentials the user will connect to SQL with.